# iOS: Pass boolean value through segue

Tags: ios, boolean

I am trying to pass a boolean from one VC to another using following code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"importaddresses"]) {
        chImportAddressBookVC *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        BOOL value = YES;
        destViewController.onboard = &(value);
    }}
```

I am using the &(value) because it it was only formulation that did not throw warning in pre-compiler. However, yes is logging to something really wierd: `@Üo<d¶“'ˇˇˇˇò•“'«‚q:tÄo<`

Can anyone suggest right way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: What warning did you get in pre-compiler for `destViewController.onboard = value;` ? And what type onboard is?

Comment: show us the declaration of onboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure, that you declared `onboard` as a pointer to BOOL instead of a plain BOOL.

something like

```
@property *BOOL onboard;
```

but it should be

```
@property BOOL onboard;
```

and than it should work simply by

```
destViewController.onboard = YES;
```

Comment: You nailed it.  Thx!